# Summing multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000 using Python

Tags: python, list, while-loop, sum, set

I've written a program meant to find the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000. The output I'm getting is `266333`, but that's not the correct answer. Please help, here is my code:

```
x = 3
y = 5
x_list = []
y_list = []

while x < 1000:
    x_list.append(x)
    x += 3

while y < 1000:
    y_list.append(y)
    y += 5

numsum = sum(x_list + y_list)
print(numsum)
```

Comment: What's it supposed to do?

Comment: What is this snippet **supposed** to do?

Comment: Hint: You are summing too much stuff, read the problem text *carefully* again. Also: do not assume that people even know what Project Euler is. Write the problem statement in the question itself.

Comment: Is there a limit on the sum function in python?

Comment: Start with replacing the first 12 lines of your code with `x=list(range(3,1000,3))` and `y=list(range(5,1000,5))`.

Comment: Imagine in which list `15` will appear...

Comment: @MattBouvier `sum` can handle everything you can throw at it. But the problem requires something more than just generating those two sequences of numbers

Comment: Ah.  Yup.  Completely overlooked overlapping values.  Thank you!

Comment: You can fix this by using a `set` to eliminate duplicates.  Change your critical line to `numsum = sum(set(x_list + y_list))`.  This results in a sum of `233168`.

Comment: Having spent some time on [codegolf.se]: `print(sum(x for x in range(1000) if x%3==0 or x%5==0))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're adding all of the numbers which are multiples of 3 and all of the numbers that are multiples of 5, which includes the numbers that are multiples of both (e.g. `15`, `30`, `45`, etc.) twice.

To simplify, let's look at the same problem, but with the multiples of 3 & 5 below 20.
After modifying the while loops to `while x < 20` & `while y < 20` respectively, we would end up with these two lists:

```
x_list = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
y_list = [5, 10, 15]
```

The current code `sum(x_list + y_list)` equates to `sum([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 5, 10, 15])`, which gives us `93`, but if you look closely, this includes 15 twice because it's a multiple of both 3 & 15, which we don't want.

What we want to do here, is to remove all duplicates from the `x_list + y_list` list, however there's no need to iterate through the lists and remove duplicates, because Python has a data type designed for this called a `set`. A set is defined in the Python documentation as "Unordered collections of unique elements", and while it may not store the order of elements within it (which can make a difference in some situations), we're just trying to not have duplicates so we can get the right sum, so we don't care what order they're in.

Continuing the simplified example, `set(x_list + y_list)` equates to `sum({3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18})` which you may notice only includes `15` once, and gives us `78`, which is 15 less than `93`.

Therefore, your second to last line should instead read `numsum = sum(set(x_list + y_list))`, which in the original situation (summing multiples of 3 & 5 below 1000) will give you `233168`. Counting all those duplicates caused the calculation to be off by `33165`.

Note: While I found this solution independently, it had previously been [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335953/summing-multiples-of-3-and-5-under-1000-using-python#comment91619377_52335953) by [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune)